# Angular 4 model - not showing error when a different model structure is used

Tags: angular

I have an account model with the following data

```
export class Account {
  public account_id: string;
  public name: string;
  public reference_id: string;
  public max_store_profiles: string;
}
```

In the component file, i define a variable as follows

```
accounts: Account[];
```

My assumption is that the accounts variable should contain only objects that has the above mentioned fields.

I get the following response on account fetch api call

```
{
  "success": true,
  "accounts_list": [
    {
      "acc_unique_id": "a086276b-e0d2-11e7-b0c9-408d5cbccb60",
      "acc_name": "Sankar account",
      "acc_reference_id": "BANFI100",
      "contact_email": "sankar@email.com"
    },
    {
      "acc_unique_id": "bbdc99b0-e0d2-11e7-b0c9-408d5cbccb60",
      "acc_name": "Soumya account 1",
      "acc_reference_id": "DEMOSP",
      "contact_email": "soumya@email.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

this is assigned to the accounts variable and is then displayed on the page.

```
this.accounts = response.accounts_list;
```

So the question is,

response.accounts_list is having different fields which is not defined in the account model. 
My assumption was that there would be an error since the structure  is not the same in the model.

How is it possible to assign this response to the accounts variable.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. You need to learn about JavaScript. There is simply no getting around that.

Comment: So what is the difference between accounts: Account[]; and accounts: any [];

Comment: `any` provides no useful information and will disable tooling support. It simply should not be used. `Account` should not be a class by the way. That it is makes your confusion worse. Take everything you know about Java and throw it away.